# J2EE : Issue with reading file - charset.MalformedInputException

Tags: java

I have an issue with this line of code :

```
Map<String, Long> wordCounts = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileSource))
                .flatMap(line -> pattern.splitAsStream(line))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                    TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```

If I run from Intellij it works fine.
If I package my application (Maven) and run it with :

> java -jar myapp.war

I am getting this error :

```
Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
```

I don't know why.

[UPDATE]
This way, the file is being created.

```
Path path = Paths.get(newTxtName);
try {
    BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    writer.append(parsedDocx);
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But there is something wrong with this line when I execute the war file on a different Server(windows 10 family) (not my pc) :

```
 Map<String, Long> wordCounts = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileSource), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

I get a

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: <fileName>
```

It works fine on my computer (windows 10 family) though, with the same war.

Comment: Probably a default charset issue.  Try adding this to your code and see if there's a dif between maven and intellij: `System.out.println("file.encoding=" + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));`.

Comment: Chances exist that you are not pointing to the same file depending you are using _IntelliJ_ or _Maven_. Is `fileSource` a `String` containing the file to read ? Then try to add a `System.out.println(new File(fileSource).getAbsolutePath());` just before your first line to see, in the two cases, what file is really opened.

Comment: with intellij I am in UTF-8 , when i run with java -jar I am in CP1252

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the character encoding of the file you are reading, then use method [lines(Path, Charset)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-) in class `java.nio.file.Files`. From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65397518/j2ee-issue-with-reading-file-charset-malformedinputexception#comment115620070_65397518) it appears that the file encoding is UTF-8. So the code in your question should be:

```java
Map<String, Long> wordCounts = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileSource),
                                           Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
                                    .flatMap(line -> pattern.splitAsStream(line))
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                                             TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
```